# Extrude individual doesn't work for edges?

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender, so I am playing around with it. I tried to recreate mesh from scratch by deleting all vertices then add them one by one. Currently, what I have is a ring of edge with no faces. I want to extrude each edge outward (in other word, extrude individually). However, there's no such option when I press Alt+E. I tried to manually click on the extrude individual at the left-side editor bar, but it becomes a group extrusion instead of individual extrusion. I am currently using the latest blender version, so I am not sure if this is one of the newer version bugs.

Do anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like David suggested, use <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude and switch to Scaling by hitting <kbd>S</kbd>:

[image: Extrude Scale Edge Ring]

(Extrusion started from the inner, unselected edge ring)

Or are you after unconnected edge rings?

[image: Duplicate Edge Ring]

They were created by using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to Duplicate.